# Design Pattern for re-trying a code block upon exception

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm trying to find a design pattern - as I'm sure one exists, this problem is common.

In my application if the user loses their Internet connection, I want to be able to pause the application, allowing the user to check their connection and retry. When a connection is successful the application leaves where it left off.

I've attempted this like so:

```
while True:
   try:
       for url in urls:
           downloadPage(url)
   except ConnectionException:
       raw_input('Connection lost. Press enter to try again')
       continue
```

But this doesn't work, because if the exception is raised within the for loop, it will catch it, but when it continues it will restart from the beginning of the `urls` list.

I do need to check for connection errors both before the application starts running, and during each request. That way I can pause it. But I don't want to litter all my code with `try/catch` blocks.

Is there a pattern for this?

Comment: A design pattern probably includes the use of continuations, however, for most use cases proper check-pointing will be sufficient (write down how far you've gotten as you're iterating through the loop, fail hard on a connection lost error, then on start read the check-point log to figure out where to continue processing).

Comment: The OP just wants to keep retrying until it works. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: By the way, there is no "catch" in Python.  The keyword you are looking for is "except"

Comment: @selbie good catch, no pun, I've been using C# and Python interchangeably today. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the try within the for loop

```
for url in urls:
    while True:
        try:
            downloadPage(url)
        except ConnectionException:
            raw_input('Connection lost. Press enter to try again')
```

Comment: this will loop forever if the connection never comes up

Comment: But then what if I create a new function, to perform other requests across the Internet like my one above, that would mean I have to repeat the same code.

Comment: @LOLKAT I don't know what you are asking. You can always just put this piece of code in a function and pass it `urls` for every call. That way you don't repeat code.

Comment: Ah, good point. Pass all requests through a function. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's what the OP wants.

Comment: I doubt they have considered it. Would you want code to run forever?

Comment: Well, they could just send it `SIGINT` (Ctrl+c) if they want to stop.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In the real code I wouldn't have it loop forever, was purely for demonstration/explination purposes. Sample code only.

Comment: @mtahmed, that would not be very well written code for a client to use

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am not trying to guess or suggest better program layout in this answer. All I am doing is answering the OP's question. I was trying to resist explaining myself but a lot of people tend to think like you are thinking right now when asked a straightforward question - guessing the overall design of the program and suggestion improvements to that design that they just made a guess for. I am answering the question, not getting the OP to improve their program. It's sample code, not the overall coding style or design of the program using this code.

Comment: @mtahmed, I presumed as per the OP's question title they were looking for a design pattern which to me would include a way to handle common cases like for instance when a connection  is down indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
while True:
   for url in urls:
       success = False
       while (not success):
           try:
               downloadPage(url)
               success = True
           except ConnectionException:
               raw_input('Connection lost. Press enter to try again')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will attempt to connect maximum of 3 times before dropping the current url and moving on to the next one. So you are not stuck if connection can't be established, but still gave a fair chance to every url.

```
for url in urls:
    retries = 3
    while True:
        try:
            downloadPage(url)
        except ConnectionException:
            retries -= 1
            if retries == 0:
                print "Connection can't be established for url: {0}".format(url)
                break            
            raw_input('Connection lost. Press enter to try again')
```

Comment: I think you mean `print "Connection can't be established for url: {0}".format(url)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: of course, a typo. Will fix. Thanks!

Comment: you could also just use `for try in range(3):` and remove the need for the while loop, if , break , etc..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: sure could :)

Answer (score 1):

You can "abstract away" the cruft in just one place (to not have to "litter all my code with try/catch blocks" as you put it) -- that's what **context managers** are for!  A simplistic example...:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def retry_forever(exception=ConnectionException, message='Connection lost. Press enter to try again'):
    while True:
        try: yield
        except exception:
            raw_input(message)
        else: break
```

Now, you can just use

```
for url in urls:
    with retry_forever():
        downloadPage(url)
```

The better variants (with max # of retries, &c) can just as elegantly be refactored into this very useful form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [retrying package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying)

Just write a block of code that keeps repeating on failure, until max retries is hit